# Change image based on another td image

Tags: jquery, image

I have this markup,

```
// we have n number of rows here, below is just a template
<tr class="row">
    <td class="optionsImg" style="display:none;">
        <img src="../status/approved-01.png" />
        <img src="../status/rejected-01.png" />
        <img src="../status/pending-01.png" />
    </td>
    <td class="statusImg">
        <img src="../status/pending-02.png" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Now on a button click,

```
$("#buttonEdit").on("click", function () { 
    $(".optionsImg").toggle();
});
```

What I want is, change source of image in `optionsImg` class based on Img src in class `statusImg`,

For example:

if `src of Img` in `statusImg` is `pending-02.png` I want to change `pending-01.png` in optionsImg class to `pending-02.png` as well instead of `pending-01.png` rest options will remain same,

Same for other images, like,

if `src Img` in `statusImg` is `approved-02.png` I want to change `approved-01.png` in optionsImg class to `approved-02.png` as well instead of `approved-01.png`

**Problem**

I am not sure how can I do it, literally can't think of where to start...

**Edit**

Edit button is located @header, it lets user to change status of a task to pending, approved and rejected, `first cell` is just the options user get when they click on edit button by default they are hidden, `second cell` is there current selected option.

01 and 02 represents colors of images, 01 is grey and 02 is colored. Hope it makes more sense now.

**Edit 2**

Now I am able to reach until this point myself,

```
$('#myTable > tbody > tr').each(function () {
      var selectedCellImg = $(this).find("statusimg img").attr('src');
      var extension = selectedCellImg // going to get name of name
});
```

Comment: where is `#buttonEdit` element

Comment: I would not base this logic on the `src` attributes. Instead I would keep a variable that kept track if status was `pending`, `approved` or `rejected`, and three variables to keep track of the counts for each status. Then I would update the image `src` based on those instead.

Comment: @Please Teach: basically wanted to know what relation button and hidden element holds.

Comment: I edited my question to make it more logical now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might not the best way of doing it and I may come back to refactor it, feel free to post better then this code and i will accept your answer,

```
$('#myTable > tbody > tr').each(function () {
      $this = $(this);
      var selectedCellImg = $(this).find(".statusimg img").attr('src');
      var childImgOrder = 0;

      if(selectedCellImg == "../status/rejected-01.png")
          childImgOrder =  1;
      else if(selectedCellImg == "../status/pending-01.png")
          childImgOrder = 2;

      var $changeMe = $($this.find(".statusImg img")[childImgOrder]);
      $changeMe.attr('src', selectedCellImg);
});
```

Hand written code above, let me know if there's any mistake.